# How to run android app in emulator by rewriting old databases?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

When I always run app to test in emulator from Eclipse , by default it never uninstalls previous one. It will maintain previous copy of database and files of the same app and run a new compiled code.

What if I want to remove all app related files, databases every time I compile and run it to test? Any settings for this in Eclipse ? I want to avoid the step of manually uninstalling it before every run. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a command prompt window open, and before launching, execute:

```
adb uninstall your.project.package
```

when using `adb install` with the `-r` modifier, the app re-installs and its data is saved. I haven't found any place in Eclipse to change this configuration, but I think this is done inside the SDK's Ant tasks. Take a look at [this class](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/1.5/development/tools/eclipse/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt/src/com/android/ide/eclipse/adt/project/ApkInstallManager.java) for more information

Comment: Yes that's what am doing currently from command line. May be the class pointed out provide some way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish part of this using a database version in any SQLiteOpenHelper subclasses, then overriding onUpgrade to drop all tables.  Actually, I suppose onUpgrade could also delete known files.

Comment: Yes but I would prefer a solution without changes in code. There must be some way I suppose to tell eclipse to make a clean start by removing all files in my app space.

Answer (score 0):

Does the "Wipe user data" under run configurations target tab wipe everything for you?  I'm not 100% what it wipes before running the app, but I suspect it clears out all the data.  You might give it a try.

Comment: "Wipe User data" resets your avd by removing all the apps. My question was simply a easy way in case when you are experimenting with database/files and want previous copies cleaned at every launch during test from eclipse.