# Is there a way to force Eclipse to automatically clean every run?

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse, build

I am developing for Android and use Eclipse to create an apk that also has a .so file with C++ code in it. My problem is that when I only change the C++ code and recompile that outside of Eclipse, Eclipse doesn't really always see that it's changed and I have to clean the project and rebuild it before I can reliably start it. This behaviour has cost me lots of time because Eclipse is not using the new .so file.

Is there a way to force Eclipse to always rebuild the project before its being run ?

Comment: Is this what your looking for?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6783744/1217328

Comment: I don't if it will fix... but have you tried to refresh the eclipse project (F5) without cleaning it? Not sure if it fixes your problem, but it is worth trying...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that but unfortunately that doesn't work. At least not the times I tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how familiar you are with ant, but if you are compiling your c++ files through command line, one thought is to create an ant build script that will:

- recompile your c++ files
- clean and build your apk
- install your apk onto your device

Then you can be sure the generated apk is always built using the latest compiled code.

Answer (score 3):

In Project Options, go to "C/C++ Build.

Select "Builder Settings" tab.

Uncheck "Use default build command" and in the field Build command, just add the target "clean" as the first target.

E.g. assuming you have

```
> make -j2 settings
```

change it to

```
> make clean -j2 settings
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to force eclipse to always clean when you press the play button. You may consider a different IDE such as IntelliJ. You never have to 'clean' a project in that so I assume they re-build the project every time you press play...

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply but unfortunately changing IDEs is not really an option.

Comment: hmmm. well then my best guess would be to check 'Wipe User Data' in your run configuration. I'm not sure if it does a full clean but it may fix your problem....