# Why controls are not being detecting after I move them to another position?

Tags: android, android-layout

Every time after I move controls to a new location in Android layout creator, it fails to type cast the controls in code.

Layout XML **Before** repositioning:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="relax.android.classes.DishesArrayAdapter" >

         <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDone"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ibtnValueDone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tvValueName"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Layout XML **After** repositioning:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="relax.android.classes.DishesArrayAdapter" >

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tvValueName"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

         <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDone"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ibtnValueDone" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**Code Sample:**

```
TextView tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
Button btnDone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDone);
```

After repositioning the control when I debug it, it throws `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView`.

I wonder how could it be wrong so as `view` is finding/detecting controls by their IDs not its position in layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean the project before debugging. so you will not get this class cast exception.

Comment: I tried to clean it with this steps: [Run a clean Android build from Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783702/run-a-clean-android-build-from-eclipse)
But it did not help. Can you suggest any other way to clean it?

Comment: Select ur project then Eclipse > Projects > Clean and rebuild the project. if the project is already installed in emaulator. uninstall and run again

Comment: Ok I got it. **Clean** option is in **Project** menu. Thanks @Taruni for responding. :)

Answer (score 1):

Clean the project & Re-Build the project and then try to debug. so you will not get this class cast exception.

Comment: thanks for responding :) . I have to clean it from Project>Clean.