# Consuming java web service in android application

Tags: java, android, web-services, noclassdeffounderror

As shown in below screenshot, I have created a web service(in java) and a client application(android app) by following [this article](http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/web-service/1145-how-create-java-web-service.html).

I also got *BUILD SUCCESSFUL* message after creating *Ant build file* under section **Create a web service client** in article and under client app 8 files are generated as shown in image(2) below.

Now when I write `HelloWebService service = new HelloWebService();` in client app, app crashes and I get following exception: 
**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mycompany.service.client.HelloWebService**

Am I doing anything wrong?

Any help appreciated.

---

[image: screenshot]

Comment: have you imported `com.mycompany.service.client.HelloWebService`?

Comment: Hmm, this is a tricky one. only thing I could say, is that eclipse deployment is screwed. try uninstalling the android app and do a clean deploy - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774526/how-to-run-android-app-in-emulator-by-rewriting-old-databases

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about your environment but from the exception the only lead is that your HelloWebService class is not found at the run time. This means you have not placed the jar containing 'HelloWebSerice' class in the classpath when you run your application. You surely have that jar when you compile your code as it compiles successfully but unfortunately it is not found by the JVM at the run time. Try putting the jar in your classpath and you should be good.

Comment: See image 2 closely. the Java files are there in the second package. he's not working with jars here

Comment: Exception is happening at run time because JVM is unable to locate the class file. The image shows the code files, which are used only at the compile time by the compiler but not at the run time

Answer (score 0):

Tick the box for your library jar in Properties -> Java Build Path -> "Order and Export" (it was listed before, but not selected)

Comment: The files are obviously there in the package. See image 2

Comment: What is your output folder for source file "Default output Folder " in source section

Comment: @VipinSahu : Sorry but I didn't get you.